# Amazon EC2 Image creation breaks docker folder if "no-reboot" option is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have AWS Linux machine running Docker with two containers.
If I create AMI with "no-reboot" option (`aws ec2 create-image --no-reboot`), when I create machine from that AMI, Docker becomes broken, for example `docker ps` command hangs forever.

I tried to remove contents of `/var/run/docker` and restart docker service. It does not help. I tried to uninstall docker from system and install it back, still no luck.

I also created AMI normally, without "no-reboot", and everything works as expected in this case.

**How does it work that no-reboot AMI creation affects this way?**
I know the docs and implications of "no-reboot" option, still it's strange how docker gets broken so hardcore.

`Docker version 1.12.6, build 7392c3b/1.12.6
Linux ip-10-0-1-124 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it's related to a lot of obsolete stopped containers in in devicemapper folder. See details: ['docker ps' hangs forever after server restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901542/docker-ps-hangs-forever-after-server-restart/42901543#42901543)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like not rebooting your instance before creating the AMI might lead to inconsistencies. [From the AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html):

> Amazon EC2 powers down the instance before creating the AMI to ensure that everything on the instance is stopped and in a consistent state during the creation process. If you're confident that your instance is in a consistent state appropriate for AMI creation, you can tell Amazon EC2 not to power down and reboot the instance. Some file systems, such as XFS, can freeze and unfreeze activity, making it safe to create the image without rebooting the instance.

Also from the same page:

> **Warning**
>
> If you choose No reboot, we can't guarantee the file system integrity of the created image.

It is probable that by using the `--no-reboot` option, you compromised some part of the file system that is crucial for Docker to run properly.

Comment: Indeed I know the implications, still it's strange that docker gets broken so hardcore, even after re-install it cannot recover. I asked this question because reboot is rarely a good option for a periodic backup.