# 'docker ps' hangs forever after server restart

Tags: docker

After server restart docker looks alive but all commands like `docker ps` hang forever until I press Ctrl+C.
What can be wrong?

`Docker version 1.12.6, build 7392c3b/1.12.6
Linux ip-10-0-1-124 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out instance had uptime for over a year, many application releases were installed, `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper` folder contained hundreds of items that apparently refer to older abandoned containers.

I saw the process of eternal reading all this data while `dockerd -D` command that runs docker interactively for debugging.

I removed `/var/lib/docker` and `/var/run/docker` and re-installed docker and containers on my box, the problem was resolved.

Feels like I need a script that would periodically remove obsolete items from docker internals.

Comment: shouldn't be too difficult with [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune) ?

Comment: @MykolaGurov Awesome!

Comment: Just want to add that solution from @MykolaGurov did also help our case. All docker command is usable again after running `docker system prune`. I believe re-installing docker will also work with longer road.

Comment: Used `dockerd -D` and found a problem container ("Sending kill signal 9 to container" never succeeded), then after `rm -rf  /var/lib/docker/containers/problem_container` dockerd could start fine