# timeout error for basic docker-compose commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I'm seeing a weird issue where basic `docker-compose` commands like `ps` and `down` time out.

```
$ docker-compose ps
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
```

There's no reason why this process should take anywhere near 60 seconds, normally it takes less than ten.

I found a stackoverflow post where ['docker ps' hangs forever after server restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901542/docker-ps-hangs-forever-after-server-restart) but `docker ps` seems to work just fine so I think it's specifically related to docker-compose. I also found some other instances of the same error on [Docker Mall](http://docker.codescode.com/docker-compose-up/) but without a solution and on [medium](https://medium.com/@apu314/hi-first-of-all-thank-you-for-your-guide-its-explained-very-well-as-i-m-new-to-docker-world-723f65e030f7) where the only advice is to increase the timeout, which doesn't help me.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
---
version: '3.7'

services:
  assets:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NPM_TOKEN: "${NPM_TOKEN}"
        IS_LCL: "TRUE"
    container_name: foobar_assets
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated
      - /app/node_modules
      - "${MESSAGING_PATH:-./node_modules/@foobar/baz}:/app/local_modules/@foobar/baz"
    ports:
      - "4005:4005"
      # - "8888:8888"
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .env-overrides
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -f http://localhost:4005/assets-manifest.json && echo 'assets are ready!'
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 100
    entrypoint: ['./rsync-entrypoint.sh']
    command: ['/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev:assets']
    init: true

  bff:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NPM_TOKEN: "${NPM_TOKEN}"
        IS_LCL: "TRUE"
    volumes:
      - .:/app:delegated
      - /app/node_modules
    container_name: foobar_bff
    links:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "4010:4010"
      - "9231:9231"
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .env-overrides
    depends_on:
      - assets
    entrypoint: ['./rsync-entrypoint.sh']
    command: ['/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev:server']
    init: true

  redis:
    image: redis:2.8
    container_name: foobar_redis

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: lcl.foobar.io
```

I'm running Docker for Mac 2.1.0.3 and have tried restarting it as well as my entire mac. This solves the problem temporarily but then it recurs.

Comment: ```service docker restart``` should restart the Docker engine.

Comment: I'm running on docker for mac, so I restart using docker desktop (v2.1.0.3 in case it's relevant) but restarting that did not help.

Comment: In that case, can you paste your Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @daudnadeem sure, just added

Comment: you're sure ```curl -f http://localhost:4005/assets-manifest.json && echo 'assets are ready!'``` works? From the error it would seem like this is timing out.